# Creating a REST call with multiple document ID's

Tags: rest, http, url

I have this URL string:

```
http://localhost:9033/api/v1/myapi/account/123456/collection/COLL12345
```

I want to amend it to also include document ID's. There could be one or more documents so I think these should be in some form of array. Should I change my API call from `GET` to `POST` and include the document ID's as a `JSON` array in the message body or is it possible to construct a URL string with them?

Answer (score 0):

You can both add them to the URI path or the URI query. I would use the query for this, something like: `/api/v1/myapi/account/123456/collection/COLL12345?ids=[1,4,5]`. You need to [URI encode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) the `[1,4,5]` part and URI decode and JSON parse it on the server.